What does "flow through the income statement rather than the balance sheet" mean in this context?
I'm reading Value: The Four Cornerstones of Corporate Finance, and in Chapter 17 Managing for Value, it talks about how to balance budget and strategy.
I understand the following paragraph, but not the meaning product or market development investments that flow through the income statement rather than the balance sheet part.

The budgeting process at many companies has become too top-down and delinked from strategy. Executives often tell us that certain investments in growth were approved during the strategy discussion (meaning product or market development investments that flow through the income statement rather than the balance sheet). But when budgeting time comes around, there's no money to spend.

Does anyone know what the author means?

Without more context (or having read the book), I might guess that this contrasts "investments" (spending which reduces income) in product or marketing against capital investments in plant and equipment which show up differently.

Expenses flow through the income statement, capital investments show up on the balance sheet.
The author describes a situation where certain marketing expenses were approved, but not budgeted. As such there's no money to pay for them. For capital investments, the full payment doesn't show up on an income statement, only the depreciation/amortization attributable to the statement period.

When a company outlines its strategy, it does not always know if it will have the income to cover all of the expenses it plans for.
The first step is to outline a strategy: what do we want to accomplish, and what do we need to do to accomplish it.  This is usually a longer-term vision; one year or more.
Next comes the actual budgeting. How much money do we have (income) and how much do we plan to spend to execute that strategy.  THis happens more frequently; quarterly or even monthly.
However, companies (just like people) can't spend money they don't have without going into more debt, which some companies are more hesitant to do than others. If their net income is less than what was planned, they will often cut expenses. Most companies will cut expenses that are pure expenses (meaning they show up as expenses on the income statement) before cutting planned asset purchases (which show up as an increase in asset on the balance sheet rather than as an "expense"). It's still "cash out the door" either way, but asset purchases are more likely to generate more revenue down the road than pure expenses (not always, but usually).
Without more context it's hard to say exactly what the author was getting at, but for a value company (as opposed to a growth company which is more willing to take on debt in order to grow) that's how I interpret it.
